# How to remove Fusion Charts Trail watermark from trail version

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

i have searched many times in online.no one give the clarity.i am using Fusion Charts trail version to export all charts in a webpage.all are working fine but i am getting "FusionCharts Trail" watermark on every chart.i want to remove that one please suggest me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to buy a full version.